# How does R adds vectors so efficiently?

Tags: r, performance

I was wondering what exactly is going on when R adds two vectors and why is it so efficient. For example why doing this:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100000,0,1)
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(100000,0,1)

diff1 <- y - x
```

is so much more faster than this:

```
diff2 <- rep(0, length(x))

for( i  in  1:length(x) ){ diff2[ i ] <- y[ i ] - x[ i ] }
```

I want to know cause I've been working with a large data set for a little while and there are some times that taking differences is not as straight forward as subtracting two vectors. In those cases I usually opt to do a loop, but I find it very inefficient and I want to figure out a better way to do it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because the vectorized version is being done by compiled C code.

Comment: The arithmetic dyadic operators have all been "vectorized" in C-code. Using a for-loop doesn't use that approach. You need to be more specific about  the "times" and the "cases" that do not lend themselves to using vectorized operators if you want any specific advice.

Comment: Check out Noam Ross' post, [Vectorization in R: Why?](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys. @jeremycg, the article was really useful.